# How to send notification before 30 days from expire date in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-channels, django-notification, django-scheduler

How do i schedule notification for this program? i am using channels to create notification and use "crontab" for scheduling but it doesn't work.

```
def my_schedule_job():

vehicle_objs = Vehicle.objects.all()


for vehicle_obj in vehicle_objs:
    insurance_expiry = vehicle_obj.insurance_expiry
    insurance_expiry_date = insurance_expiry - timedelta(days=5)
    today = date.today()

    print('insurance_expiry_date',insurance_expiry_date)
    print('today',today)

    if insurance_expiry_date == today:
        notification_obj = Notification(user_id=vehicle_obj.user_id,notification="Your insurance for {} will expire on {}".format(vehicle_obj.vehicle,insurance_expiry) ,is_seen=False)
        notification_obj.save()
    elif insurance_expiry_date <= today:
        notification_obj = Notification(user_id=vehicle_obj.user_id,notification=vehicle_obj.vehicle + " insurance is going to expire on " + str(insurance_expiry),is_seen=False)
        notification_obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to create a custom `manage.py` command to solve your problem.  To do so, you'll want to create an `<appname>/management/commands` directory structure and put your code in a file in that directory with the file name for the code bearing the name of the command you want to run.  For example, `emails.py`.

After that, there are functions that Django expects to see present in your custom management command.  You'll want to place your code into the respective functions.

Review [this URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and let me know if you run into issues?

Good luck.